# native module cannot be null react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to integrate dfp ads in react native by using the following npm library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-admob-dfp/v/2.0.0-beta.3.9

I have created the google ads account and using UnitId and appId from there.

I have also add `pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'` in info.plist and run `pod install --repo-update` command on terminal by using this page https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk

here is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

import {
  AdMobBanner,
  AdMobRewarded,
  AdMobInterstitial,
  PublisherBanner,
} from 'react-native-admob-dfp';


export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>

        <AdMobBanner
        adSize="banner"
        adUnitID="ca-app-pub-6646918965554902/2457848975"
        testDevices={[AdMobBanner.simulatorId]}
        onAdFailedToLoad={error => console.error(error)} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is linking, ios or android ?

Comment: the problem is linking, ios or android ?

Comment: both android and iOS.

Comment: pod 'react-native-admob', path: '../node_modules/react-native-admob' read https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob also try react-native link name-of-repo

Comment: Do I need to add "pod 'react-native-admob', path: '../node_modules/react-native-admob' " this manually.? However I am doing react-native link name-of -repo

Comment: yes manually then pod install

Comment: okay, I will try and get back to you. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried that but again getting error as: CompileC /Users/name/Desktop/ReactNative/UpdatedReactNative_v3.0.1/DfpAds1/ios/build/DfpAds1/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RNAdMobManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNAdMobManager.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNGADBannerViewManager.o /Users/vicky/Desktop/ReactNative/UpdatedReactNative_v3.0.1/DfpAds1/node_modules/react-native-admob-dfp/ios/RNGADBannerViewManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RNAdMobManager' from project 'RNAdMobManager')